# Serialize a PropertyGrid (SerializeToXML) failed

Tags: c#, xmlserializer, propertygrid

I try to serialize a PropertyGrid and write the results to a XML file. At the end the XML file is almost empty;
 XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyBookCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

My Code;

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyBookCollection  MyBooks = new MyBookCollection ();

    SerializeToXML(MyBooks);
}

public void SerializeToXML(MyBookCollection MyBooks)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyBookCollection ));
    TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"D:\BookInfo.xml");
    serializer.Serialize(textWriter, MyBooks);
    textWriter.Close();
}
}

[Serializable]
public class MyBookCollection 
{
     string m_Title;
     [Category("Book Titles")]
     [ReadOnly(true)]
     public string Title
     {
         get { return m_Title; }
         set { m_Caption = Title; }
     }
 }
```

**What's wrong or how to do it better** 
Language: C#

Comment: As the code is written, the btnSave_Click() just create and serialize an empty MyBookCollection object ?

Comment: Yes. See also comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to get the .SelectedObject property this way ?

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var MyBooks = myProertyGrid.SelectedObject as MyBookCollection;
    SerializeToXML(MyBooks);
}
```

The PropertyGrid does unfortunately not bind property changes.

Comment: excellent. That's the trick ! Useful and accepted your answer.

Comment: I tried this code; but I get following error: Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's wrong with the XML. 
Your XML serialization is ok!

You only see your MyBookCollection node because there is no other data present in the object!

Kind regards,
Wim

Comment: How to get the object filled. The PropertyGrid contains all data and `SelectedObject` is set to `MyBookCollection`.